# How to post massive data to html with Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, web-applications

I am building a python web app with Flask.

I got 3 lists (same length) with about 3,000 data each from my python code.

And like to make them into a table in the html file,
how should I write the html template (the tr, td things).

I could only find tutorial about passing one single variable to html.

If there are any references for me to study I will appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to achieve this.

Create a rest api with some url like http://yoursite/data which gives this large data in json format.

Then use a ajax calls to fetch data and use javascript/angular/jquery script to fill the data into html table.

Some refs:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

[Using jQuery to build table rows from Ajax response (Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724017/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-response-json)

[Populate html table on jquery success event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048922/populate-html-table-on-jquery-success-event)

Answer (score 0):

Since [Flask uses Jinja2](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templating/), you can take [Jinja2 Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/) as reference.